# What's Python JSON serializable?

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have two ways to represent Python object by `json.dumps()`

First:

```
person = {
"name": "John",
"age": 30,
"city": "New York"
}
```

Second:

```
class Person:
   def _init_(self, name, age, city):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
      self.city = city

person = Person("John", 30, "New York")
```

Then I tried `p1 = json.dumps(person)`, the second way would say `it's not JSON serializable`.

So basically for Python, json.dumps only work for built-in object like dict object?

Comment: Yes; by default, the `json` module only knows how to serialize built-in types. Look at [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) to see how to serialize instances of your own classes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `json` module only knows how to serialize certain built-in types. An easy way to work with classes that have "fields" is the `dataclasses` module.

Example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import json

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
    city: str

person = Person("John", 30, "New York")
print(json.dumps(asdict(person)))
```

The `asdict()` function converts the dataclass instance into a `dict` which `json` can serialize.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about vanilla Python, serialization could be done this way:

```py
import json


class Person:
   def __init__(self, name, age, city):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
      self.city = city

   def to_json(self):
       return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)


person = Person("John", 30, "New York")
print(person.to_json())
```

So we're just converting an object to a dict using `__dict__` attribute.

But if you need something more sophisticated, you might need `DRF` (Django REST Framework) or `pydantic`. An example how it could be done with DRF:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer


class Person:
   def __init__(self, name, age, city):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
      self.city = city


class PersonSerializer(Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    age = serializers.IntegerField()
    city = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Person(**validated_data)


person = Person("John", 30, "New York")
print(PersonSerializer(person).data)
```

This way you have a much better control over it. See [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.6+ you can use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) in Python along with the `asdict` helper function to convert a dataclass instance to a Python `dict` object.

> Note: For 3.6, you'll need a [backport](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/) for the `dataclasses` module, as it only became a builtin to Python starting in 3.7.

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
    city: str


person = Person("John", 30, "New York")
person_dict = asdict(person)

json_string = json.dumps(person_dict, indent=2)

print(json_string)
```

Out:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "New York"
}
```

---

If you have a more complex use case, or end up with needing to (de)serialize a nested dataclass model, I'd check out an external library like the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) that supports such a use case in particular.